# Conditional redirecting rules in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to apply the following rules in my .htaccess file-

- Don't redirect if the url is `mysite.com`
- Don't redirect if the url is `mysite.com/index.php` or `mysite.com/anypage.anyextension`
- Don't redirect if the url has the word **admin** after domain as `mysite.com/admin/...`
- Redirect if the url has the pattern `mysite.com/anyword/` or `mysite.com/anyword` to `mysite.com/somewhere/somepage.php?slug=anyword`

.htaccess is a completely new world to me.
Could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to have a specific folder perform a redirect, for example a news folder the template would be

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^news/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    /news/index.php?slug=$1    [NC,L,QSA]    # Process posted item
```

This redirects `yousite.com/news/my-first-article` to `yoursite.com/news/index.php?slug=my-first-article`

Just be sure to replace news and index.php with the pages actually handling the command